# How can i click on the login button in selenium webdriver of website Http://Phptravels.Com/Demo/

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver

I want to click on login button. Which attribute should I use to click on login button? I am new to selenium web driver. I am unable to find its link text, id, class name, name. I am not able to find its XPath or CSS selector. please advice me with the code. Image is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GttY.png)

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either Xpath which is

```
.//*[@id='main-menu']/ul/li[8]/a
```

or CSS Selector which is

```
.login
```

Answer (score 0):

To click on element with text as **LOGIN** within the url `https://phptravels.com/404/` you can use either of the [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `CssSelector`:

  ```
  "a.login[href='http://phptravels.org']>span"
  ```
- `XPath`:

  ```
  "//a[@class='login' and @href='http://phptravels.org']/span[contains(.,'LOGIN')]"
  //or
  "//a[@class='login' and @href='http://phptravels.org']/span[contains(.,'Login')]"
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options, just avoid using xpath since its an overkill

```
li.user-login>a.login>span
```

or

```
a.login>span
```

or xpath

```
.//a[@class='login']/span[text()='Login']
```